# Apex Custom Wrapper wrong property assignment

Tags: apex, wrapper-class

I've created the following wrapper:

```
public class MyWorkWrapper {
    public String sobjectName;
    public String ownerName;
    public String recordId;
    public String recordNumber;
    public String subject;
    public String recordType;
    public String recordTypeDevName;
    public String status;
    public String priority;
    public String requester; 
    public String lastModifiedDate;
    public String caseMilestones;

    public List<String> recordNumberOptions;
    public List<String> subjectOptions;
    public List<String> statusOptions;
    public List<String> priorityOptions;
    public List<String> ownerNameOptions;
    public List<String> recordTypeOptions;
    public List<String> lastModifiedDateOptions;
    public List<String> requesterOptions;
}
```

And I have the following logic which populates one of the wrapper's properties:

```
                if(myWorkWrapper.status != null && !myWorkWrapper.statusOptions.contains(myWorkWrapper.status)) {
                    System.debug('1 ' + myWorkWrapper.priorityOptions);
                    myWorkWrapper.statusOptions.add(myWorkWrapper.status);
                    System.debug('2 ' + myWorkWrapper.priorityOptions);
                }
```

But for some reason

```
myWorkWrapper.statusOptions.add(myWorkWrapper.status)
```

populates **myWorkWrapper.statusOptions** (normal behavior) as well as **myWorkWrapper.priorityOptions** (wrong behavior)

[image]

Any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: Both properties will be referencing the same list. You need to make sure each property has its own list instance.

Comment: @PhilW It helped! Thank you so much!